# readonly property on input does not prevent the keyboard to show

Tags: ionic2, ionic3, ionic2-datetime

I am trying to use a native date picker in Ionic 2 by handling the click event on the input:

```
<ion-item>
    <ion-label stacked>Start</ion-label>
    <ion-input type="datetime" readonly="true" placeholder="Choose a date" formControlName="date" (click)="onDateClick($event)" tappable></ion-input>
  </ion-item>
```

But the `readonly` property does not seem to prevent the keyboard to show one first time, I have to click again in order to get the native date picker to show (handled in `onDateClick($event)`).

I tried to use the `disabled` property, which works but the style is different and somehow it looks like it is not a good pattern when using Reactive Forms...

Any idea how to prevent this first show of the keyboard?

***** EDIT *****

Here is the `onDateClick` function

```
onDateClick(e: Event) {
    console.log('NewEventPage#onDateClick');

    if (this.platform.is('cordova')) {
      this.datePicker.show({
        date: new Date(),
        mode: 'datetime',
        allowOldDates: false
      }).then(
        date => {
          console.log('Picked date ', date);
          this.startDate = moment(date);
          this.newEventForm.get('date').setValue(moment(date).format('LLLL'));
        },
        err => console.log('Error occurred while getting date: ', err)
      );
    } else {
      let tmp = new Date();
      this.startDate = moment(tmp);
      this.newEventForm.get('date').setValue(moment(tmp).format('LLLL'));
    }
  }
```

Comment: question asked long time ago... but did you ever find a solution?

Answer (score 1):

do it like this:

```
<ion-item>
    <ion-label stacked>Start</ion-label>
    <ion-input type="datetime" [readonly]="true" placeholder="Choose a date" formControlName="date" (click)="onDateClick($event)" tappable></ion-input>
  </ion-item>
```

`readonly` is the input property of ion-input that's why it has to be written inside the brackets. You can find more info [here](https://ionicframework.com/docs/api/components/input/Input/).

Comment: The problem remains event with your solution (despite the fact that indeed it looks like the right way to implement it)

Comment: @Manuel What exactly are you doing on click event?

Comment: Just updated my post so that you can see what the click event function does